# mysql request - looking for not existing record

Tags: mysql

I have a a simple classroom reservation system, with two tables :

Room :

```
 1. id
 2. name
 3. localisation
```

calendar :

```
 1. id
 2. idroom
 3. year
 4. month
 5. days
```

days is a string of 31 characters (1 character by day). Characters could be : "0" for free; "1" for first-step reservation; "3" for occupied

the calendar is created when needed, so my problem is when I ask for the not occupied classrooms, to get the classrooms which have no calendar entry for the period I check.
for example classroom1 is occupied from 01/12/2013 to 03/02/2013 and I have no more entry
in my calendar table for this classroom. And I don't know how to have classroom1 in my result if I ask for a reservation from 01/12/2013 to 04/12/2013. Month could be null and year too.
I try left join, and "is null" but didn't succeed.

This is the first part of my request, which works, but doesn't display "the room with no calendar" for the period:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room.id
FROM room LEFT JOIN
     calendar
     ON room.id=calendar.idroom
WHERE (calendar.year=2013 AND calendar.month=12 and calendar.days like "0000%")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT room.id FROM room LEFT JOIN calendar ON room.id=calendar.idroom WHERE (calendar.year=2013 AND calendar.month=12 and calendar.days like "0000%") OR calendar.id is null" doesn't work?

Comment: You are aware that putting a 31 character 'bitfield' in 'days' is actually a violation of a lot of normalization rules? Whilst not necessarily 'bad practice' per se, I would consider refactoring that into a separate table `days`.

Comment: @NIels : I didn't wrote the script and it's a little part of a bigger system... I  just try to make my best to do is works.

Comment: @Melanie : Thank you for your answer. It seems to a good clue :-) But I don't exactly understand what means the "calendar.id is null". Doesn't means there no calendar the for the period (01/12/2013 to 04/12/2013)? or for month/year??

Comment: @Melanie: I finish my tests and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `where` clause uses the `calendar` table, so it is undoing the effect of the `left join`.  You can fix this by mixing the logic into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room.id
FROM room LEFT JOIN
     calendar
     ON room.id=calendar.idroom and
        (calendar.year=2013 AND calendar.month=12 and calendar.days like "0000%")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tested the "ON" clause. And the problem is that I'll get all the rooms... Don't really understand how it works...